# Using "save" function in GUI .m file

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I am attempting to save a file that is titled based on user input from a GUI.  I receive an error when I enter the following into the callback function of a pushbutton:

```
Category='Food';
Rating='5';
save(strcat(Category,Rating,'Data.mat'),'VariableName')
```

However, I do not receive an error, and the variable saves correctly if I enter these exact same three lines of code at the command line.  Why is that and how can I get the variable to save as a filename dictated by user input in the pushbutton's callback function?

Comment: What's does the error say?

Comment: Maybe because you don't have access to the base workspace from your GUI? Read e.g. here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/273624

Comment: The error reads...


Error using save
Argument must contain a string.